# InDesign: Can I use a variable in a cross-reference?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cross-reference

I have a book with many documents; each begins with a numbered "Chapter" paragraph style. Rather that numbering all the chapters manually, I use a variable for the chapter numbers. However, when I create a cross-reference to one of the chapters, the chapter number is omitted. So instead of getting this...

> For more information, see Chapter 6: Combat.

I get this instead...

> For more information, see Chapter : Combat.

The obvious workaround is to get rid of the variables and manually number all the chapters. This is less that ideal because I will have to re-number the chapters when I add new content to the book later.

Is InDesign really unable to capture variable information in a cross-reference?

Comment: I am confused with "numbered" word you used. Do you mean your Chapter paragraph is set as unnumbered "Chapter + variable (chapter number)" or as a numbered list "Chapter ^#"?

Comment: Chapter + variable (chapter number)

Comment: OK, see answer ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set cross reference like this: **<paraText /> <chapNum />**

Edit: Ok after re-reading your question, I understand you'll be facing a problem: your variable is in the middle of your paragraph text (paraText). So the result would be "Chapter: Combat 6". Not good ^^
 So I suggest this: Set your paragraph style as a numbered list. In the "Number" field, delete marks and just type Chapter+space. This way you'll be able to set your cross reference like this: **<paraNum /> <chapNum /> <paraText />** It should do the trick.

Or (even easier): Number as **Chapter ^H**, then cross-ref: <paraNum />  <paraText />

Hope that helps ^^

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good work around. I'll try it. I guess inDesign cannot simply capture variable information the way I am using it. It needs some extra steps to make it work, such as those you suggested.